# Sorting rows based on expression values in SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

Newbie to SSRS here.

I have a report as shown below in the image. Each Expr is a complex custom expression and they return a percentage value. The grouping is Agencies -> States -> National. I need to sort rows in descending order based on the States' overall value i.e. if State 1's overall is 80%, State 2's overall is 85% and State 3's overall is 75% then the rows associated with State 2 should appear at the top, followed by State 1 and lastly State 3.

Any help/pointer with this is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

P.S - The expr in Agency and State overall uses custom code "=Code.GetAgencyOverall" and "=Code.GetStateOverall" because of underlying complex calculations.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0qum.png)

Answer (score 0):

Right click to `Agency` group in `Row Groups` pane, go to `Group properties...`. In the `Sorting` tab add a new row, use the overall expression by pressing the `Fx` button, also select `Z-A` for descending.

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: alejandro zuleta - Thanks for the quick response. I tried what you said and I get the error "A sort expression for the Tablix refers to a report item. Report items cannot be used in sort expressions". Sorry I missed mentioning: The expr in Agency and State overall uses custom code "=Code.GetAgencyOverall" and "=Code.GetStateOverall". I need to use custom code because the overalls are not a direct average and have more calculations to it.

Comment: @user6596238, share the code of the custom function.

Comment: @user6596238, What data do TextboxElement's hold?

Comment: @ alejandro zuleta - they hold percentages.

Comment: Is it data from another tablix or the same tablix that you are trying to sort? You can't sort a tablix using fields from another dataset/tablix.

Comment: It is data from the same Tablix. The Report has just one Tablix.

Comment: could you provide the query you are using for building your dataset? I think this requeriment cannot be done using pure SSRS, I'd create another dataset for determining the Agency order.

Comment: The dataset is built using a Stored Proc. and the Stored Proc. is 1800 lines long. There are more calculations in custom expressions fx that run on the output of Stored Proc. I don't know if creating another dataset would help because I still need to use the output from expressions. Your thoughts please. Thank you.

Comment: @user6596238 I'd try to calculate the Overall value for every agency in the SP and rank every agency using its overall. It won't affect another custom functions since the structure of the SP will be kept.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm not sure if that can be done because the overalls must be run on the KPI values generated for each agency. Thanks for your timely response and help. Much appreciated.